# Can I feed options into JS plugin from variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a JS plugin, which I want to trigger for every instance of an element.

However, I want the options for the plugin to be different for different cases.

```
if(something) {
    var options = {
        itemSelectText: 'Some text',
        searchPlaceholderValue: 'Search for something'
    }
} else {
    var options = {
        itemSelectText: 'Some other text',
        searchPlaceholderValue: 'Search for something else'
    }
}

const choices = new Choices(dropdown, 
    options
);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean? The code you show here should work and give you different `options` based on `something`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let options = {};

if(something) {
    options = {
        itemSelectText: 'Some text',
        searchPlaceholderValue: 'Search for something'
    }
} else {
    options = {
        itemSelectText: 'Some other text',
        searchPlaceholderValue: 'Search for something else'
    }
}

const choices = new Choices(dropdown, 
    options
);
```

Comment: Spot on, thanks. Following up - what if I wanted to have some options which apply to both, without having to repeat them?

Comment: `options = {...options, myProp: 'myValue'}`

Answer (score 2):

You can declare your `options` variable as empty, outside of the scope of your if statement, and then set it inside of the if statement.

```
let options;

if (something) {
    options = {
        itemSelectText: 'Some text',
        searchPlaceholderValue: 'Search for something'
    }
} else {
    options = {
        itemSelectText: 'Some other text',
        searchPlaceholderValue: 'Search for something else'
    }
}
```